# GitLab trigger a child pipeline without retriggering the parent pipeline

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a CI build on GitLab which builds a docker image.

I would like to extend the CI to be able to trigger sub-pipelines from outside the project to use the docker image and continue with some processes.

When triggering the sub-pipeline, is it possible to avoid rebuilding the CI of the parent pipeline and use the current docker image?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your workflow you have different approaches, but in this case as it seems that you're not making use of any Artifact Registry - so assuming your Docker image is only local - you can store it as an artifact on your parent pipeline and then use it on the child pipeline.

That would look something like this:

```
## Parent pipeline job
build:
  stage: build
  trigger: my/downstream_project
  script:
    - docker build . -t app
    - mkdir image
    - docker save app > image/app.tar
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - image

## Child pipeline job
child-job:
  stage: test
  needs:
    - project: my/upstream_project
      job: build
      ref: main
      artifacts: true
  script:
    - docker load -i image/app.tar
    - docker run --name app -d app
    - docker exec app npm run lint-test
```

The `build` job on your parent pipeline will save the Docker image as an artifact and then on the downstream (child) pipeline job `child-job` you can use it. By adding the `needs` key, the job will inherit the artifacts from the upstream job.